# VB.NET - Polymorphism and interfaces

Tags: .net, vb.net, oop

I am trying to understand multiple inheritance in interfaces.  I have borrowed the code from the following website and converted it to VB.NET: http://www.oodesign.com/interface-segregation-principle.html

```
Public Interface IWorker
    Inherits IFeedable, IWorkable
End Interface

Public Interface IWorkable
    Sub work()
End Interface

Public Interface IFeedable
    Sub eat()
End Interface

Public Class Worker
    Implements IWorkable, IFeedable
    Public Sub eat() Implements IFeedable.eat

    End Sub

    Public Sub work() Implements IWorkable.work

    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Robot
    Implements IWorkable

    Public Sub work() Implements IWorkable.work

    End Sub
End Class

Class Manager
    Dim worker As IWorkable

    Public Sub setWorker(ByVal w As IWorkable)
        worker = w
    End Sub

    Public Sub manage()
        worker.work()
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Form1
       Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
            Try
                Dim Test As New Manager
                Dim IWorkerRobot As IWorkable = New Robot
                Test.setWorker(IWorkerRobot)

            Catch ex As Exception
                'I won't absorb the exception.  
            End Try
        End Sub
    End Class
```

I don't understand what the point of the IWorker interface is now that there is a IWorkable and IFeedable interface (IWorker extends IFeedable and IWorkable).  I realize that this it will have something to do with polymorphism but I am not sure.

Comment: There is no point in defining IWorker in the snippet, simply because you don't use it.  Arbitrarily extend the definition of a robot, it has to eat too.  Just in a completely different way from, say, a human, it is going to have to plug itself into a wall socket to recharge its battery.

Comment: @Hans Passant, when is it valid to have an inheritance hierarchy?

Comment: When you have an **is-a** relationship between classes.  No evidence for that in your snippet, a Manager is not a Robot.  But that applies to classes, not interfaces.  Your IWorker simply declares an interface that permits a client that uses the interface to ask for both eating and working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends entirely on the code that's using the object.  That's where it actually gets "polymorphed."

- If the object is being used in a block of code that only needs an `IWorkable` then it will be used as an `IWorkable`.
- If the object is being used in a block of code that only needs an `IFeedable` then it will be used as an `IFeedable`.
- If the object is being used in a block of code that needs *both* then it will be used as an `IWorker`.  (To that end, your `Worker` class should probably implement all three interfaces so it can be used as an `IWorker`.)

The main point is that *none* of these blocks of code need to know or care whether they're operating on a `Worker` or a `Robot` or a `Manager`.

In generalized code (see the [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) as a common example) polymorphism comes into play by interpreting an object as another type.  If that object can polymorph into that type (through interfaces, inheritance, any form of object abstraction) then it can be used as such.  The same object in memory can be interpreted as any time that it implements.

Comment: Thanks.  In that case what is the point of the inheritance in the interfaces? Why would the worker class have to implement all three interfaces to be a IWorker?

Comment: @w0051977: So that calling code can use both the `IWorkable` and `IFeedable` functionality without having to polymorph the object twice.  A single type, `IWorker`, covers all of the needed functionality.  Calling code which needs both can use `IWorker`, calling code which needs only one can use that specific one.  Requiring the calling code to polymorph the object twice can often be ugly and more difficult to maintain.

Comment: That does make sense.  You can use the IWorker interface and create an instance of an object that implements either IFeedable or IWorkable (please correct me if I am wrong).  In that case, why would the Worker class have to implement all three interfaces? Could it not just implement IWorker?

Comment: @w0051977: Possibly, yes.  I'm not sure off the top of my head if the compiler would be smart enough, honestly.  Of course, your unit tests confirm whether or not that works, right? :)

Comment: I really like this question/answer, and it is helping me understand polyM very well, but I have an additional question.  Many people site future [expandability/supportability/compatibility] to be a big reason to use this methodology (among other reasons, to avoid having to [recompile/redist] the entire codeline).  Can anyone give an example (here or in another answer) of how this would work?  Say, for instance, that Worker at some later point needed to be 'Sleepable', or some similar valid request for expanded functionality.  Unless I am misunderstanding something.